# Specify scope in Device code flow in @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

I have been using @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth library for interactive login(https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/blob/master/lib/login.ts#L428) from command line to do a device login flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code#protocol-diagram. As can be seen in the doc, login involves a call to /deviceCode endpoint with client-id and scope as input. However in the @azure/ms-rest-nodeAuth library login, there is no provision to send scope during login, preventing user from being able to give consent for scopes.

Here is the code I have tried

```
  const creds = await interactiveLogin({domain: "89d3889c-03f7-4b95-922c-393eefc1b12c",
  tokenAudience: "5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706"});
  const token = await creds.getToken(); 
  console.log(token);
```

This is the error I get on login. I didn't get any consent screen.

```
AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: 04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46(Microsoft Azure CLI). Resource value from request: 5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706. Resource app ID: 5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706. List of valid resources from app registration: .
```

I also tried

```
  const creds = await interactiveLogin({domain: "89d3889c-03f7-4b95-922c-393eefc1b12c",
  tokenAudience: "api://5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706/.default"});
  const token = await creds.getToken(); 
  console.log(token);
```

I got

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706/.default was not found in the tenant named 89d3889c-03f7-4b95-922c-393eefc1b12c. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

Comment: please set  tokenAudience as `api://5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706/`

Comment: Does not work. AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706/ was not found in the tenant named 89d3889c-03f7-4b95-922c-393eefc1b12c. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: According to the error, you should use admin use to login and do admin consent

Comment: I have not defined any scope on this. Why is admin consent required?

Comment: The sdk use azure ad v1.0 endpoint. When you set `tokenAudience`, it will get token with  all of the resource's scope you have configured fro the application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources.

Comment: what happens when no scopes are defined, as in my case?

Comment: It will get token with `https://management.core.windows.net/`: https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/blob/4bbceb1dc3c6c9928b6c8257a4b3d98b8e71913a/lib/login.ts#L428 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/ms-rest-azure-env

Comment: I'm not getting this token.

Comment: Could you please describe it in detaail?

Comment: Yes, there are no scopes defined in the AD app, and I'm requesting for a token with AD app as audience as specified in my question and receiving error as described in my question.

Comment: We have no way to do that. if you want to get azure ad token with some scope. you must ensure that your client application has been configured these scope.

Comment: but Im using ADAL based library, which does not require scope.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my word. I want to tell you that you should configure the permissions in your AD application you use to get token via Azure Portal before you run the code.

Comment: I want to get token for this resource - 5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706. I want the user to consent for this after login. But consent screen does not come with ADAL. It comes with MSAL. Is there a way to get consent screen with ADAL?

Comment: Register a client AD application in your tenant.  The configure resource `5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706` for the application. Then run code `const authres = await msRestNodeAuth.interactiveLoginWithAuthResponse({
      clientId: "<your client app application id>",
      domain: "<>",
      tokenAudience: "5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706",
    });`

Comment: By default the client id is that of Azure CLI SDK, I want to use it and I want user to  consent to the client accessing the resource at time of login. Is it possible to achieve this with ADAL?

Comment: We have no way to do that with  client id is that of Azure CLI SDK. Because we cannot configure other API permissions fro the application.

Comment: But then it works with MSAL where user consents at run time.

Comment: Because msal use Azure AD endpoint v2.0. It supports dynamic  scope.

Comment: ok got it. since ADAl does not support dynamic scope, it must be pre authorized. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The package `@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth` uses Azure AD v1.0 endpoint to do auth. So we have no way to provide scope value and we just can provide resource value. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources). Regarding how to provide it, we can init `tokenAudience` as resource value in `InteractiveLoginOptions` value.
[image]

For example

```
var msRestNodeAuth = require("@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth");
async function main() {
  try {
    const authres = await msRestNodeAuth.interactiveLoginWithAuthResponse({
      clientId: "d8aa****-adbe-a1ad3c1dfd8d",
      domain: "",
      tokenAudience: "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    });
    const token = await authres.credentials.getToken();
    console.dir(token);
  } catch (error) {}
}

main();
```

[image]

Comment: but how to get user consent? Without user consent, the login fails down the line.

Comment: @user3740951 Could you please provide error message or screenshot?

Comment: @user3740951 As far as I knew, if we use device code flow to get token, we need to open a browser and enter the url.  When we do that, we will do consent if  your organization users do not do admin consent.

Comment: @user3740951 Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I have added the code and the errors. I am not getting a consent screen.

Comment: @user3740951 please set tokenAudience as `api://5cf9ab4d-05af-4bc0-b7f9-6e4b0c236706/`